# Where clause in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm confused about how the **where clause** in Haskell works in a certain situation.

My biggest question is, is it possible **to declare a variable** that does something in the **where clause** and **use back** that declared variable through **another variable** declared in the where clause?

For example:

```
someFunc :: somefunc
.
| (guard expression)
| (guard expression)
where a = 1+3
      b = a + 2 --using back 'a' variable which was also declared in the where clause.
```

Is this possible? When i do this haskell does not report any error but I was having doubts if it's a correct.

Comment: Have you tried it? Yes, it's possible, and the definition of `b` doesn't even need to come after the definition of `a`; `... where { b = a + 2; a = 1 + 3 }` works just as well.

Comment: Yes, and you can even use the *same* variable, like `a = 1 + a`, here this is a bit dangerous, but for example `where lst = 1 : lst` is sometimes used to declare an infinite list that will for some operations require constant memory.

Comment: Why are you people answering in the comments?!?!

Comment: @Libby: because it looks like the `where` clause of a question syntactically :)

Comment: @Libby I answered in the comments because it's not a well-asked question. The OP ask whether perfectly good code works without apparently even trying it.

Comment: @Libby Indeed we should not answer in comments. Still, sometimes the question seems unclear, so the comment is implicitly asking "is this the kind of answer you seek?". Further, I guess that other times the answer looks so trivial that the comment-writer feels uneasy with posting it as an answer, perhaps believing that would be a shameful rep-grabbing move. SO policy is of course that answers should be answers, not comments (and we have CW for who does not want rep, in theory). I'm not a psychologist, but this is my guess :)

Answer (score 8):

Yes. The variables in the `where` clause can see other variables in the same `where` clause.

For doubts, you can test it out with a simpler structure to see if it gives the correct value:

```hs
testing = b
  where
    a = 1000
    b = a + 234

main = print testing
```

Does it print out 1234 as expected?

Answer (score 7):

**Yes**, it is even possible to use the *same* variable in the expression as the one you define.

would work as well. In essence, the variables are just references to "expressions". So for your case you construct something that looks like:

```
    ┏━━━━━━━┓
b──>┃  (+)  ┃
    ┣━━━┳━━━┫   ┏━━━┓
    ┃ o ┃ o─╂──>┃ 2 ┃
    ┗━┿━┻━━━┛   ┗━━━┛
      │
      v
    ┏━━━━━━━┓
a──>┃  (+)  ┃
    ┣━━━┳━━━┫   ┏━━━┓
    ┃ o ┃ o─╂──>┃ 3 ┃
    ┗━┿━┻━━━┛   ┗━━━┛
      │
      │         ┏━━━┓
      ╰────────>┃ 1 ┃
                ┗━━━┛
```

This expression tree thus contains functions which point to other expression trees. Haskell will by default *not* evaluate these expressions: the expressions are evaluated lazily: only when you have to calculate these, you will calculate the corresponding value. Furthermore, if you are for example interested in the value of `b`, you thus will calculate the value of `a`, and thus the `1+3` expression will only be evaluated *once*. The same holds in the opposite direction: in case you first evaluate `a`, then evaluating `b` will benefit from the fact that `a` was already calculated. You can for example define two variables in terms of each other, like:

```
foo :: Int
foo = a
    where a = 1 + b
          b = 1 + a
```

but this will get stuck in an infinite loop since you will create an expression that looks like `1 + (1 + (1 + (...)))`.

We can even define a variable in terms of itself. For example the function below generates an infinite list of ones:

```hs
ones :: [Int]
ones = lst
    where lst = 1 : lst
```

This will be represented as:

```
      ┏━━━━━━━┓
lst──>┃  (:)  ┃<─╮
      ┣━━━┳━━━┫  │
      ┃ o ┃ o─╂──╯
      ┗━┿━┻━━━┛
        │
        v
      ┏━━━┓
      ┃ 1 ┃
      ┗━━━┛
```

Comment: Nice art.  I was hoping someone would show an example like `lst`.

Answer (score 1):

```
calcProfit revenue cost= if revenue - cost >0
                         then revenue - cost
                         else 0
```

In this example we are repeating (revenuw-cost) your computation. This is a cheap operation but if it was an expensive operation you would be wasting resources. To prevent this, we use `where` clause:

```
calcProfit revenue cost = if profit >0 
                          then profit
                          else 0
           where profit= revenue-cost
```

With "where" clause we reverse the normal order used to write variables. In most of the  programming languages, variables are declared before they’re used. In Haskell, because of referential transparency, variable order isn’t an issue.

As you see, we declare the variable "profit" in where clause and then we used it